# FirebaseFirestore insertion

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
public class Post extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String TAG = null;
private TextView titleView;
private Button create_post_button;
private EditText post_title,post_description;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private ProgressBar progressBar;
private FirebaseFirestore db;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_post);
        mAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar2);

        titleView=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.titleView);
        post_title=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.post_title);
        post_description=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.post_description);
        create_post_button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.create_post_button);

        create_post_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()  {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                createPost();
            }
        });
    }

     public void createPost() {
        String title_val = post_title.getText().toString().trim();
        String post_description_val = post_description.getText().toString().trim();
        String user_id=mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(title_val) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(post_description_val)) {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Map<String, String> posts = new HashMap<>();
            posts.put("description",post_description_val);
            posts.put("title", title_val);
            posts.put("user_id", user_id);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            db.collection("posts")
                    .add(posts)
                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentReference>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(DocumentReference documentReference) {
                            Toast.makeText( Post.this,"Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    })
                    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            Log.w( TAG,"Error adding document", e);
                        }});}}}
```

Its not being inserted into db,neither it gives any error.I don't understand where the error is!I don't know what is wrong since everything is from **android** main page.If it is some logic error please let me know!
*Some help would be appreciated! Thanks in advance!*

Comment: Since you're using a Map instead of a POJO, have you tried using db.collection("posts").document().set(posts)...?

Comment: @HondaGuy no I havent tried can you please write the full instruction..

Comment: @HondaGuy I tried even with set the same problem

Comment: just tested your code, checkout the answer

Comment: @LeviAlbuquerque take a look at the code above,it still doesnt work,what can be wrong

Comment: Does this line of code return something `Log.w( TAG,"Error adding document", e);`?

Comment: @AlexMamo it doesnt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because you're accessing the variables wrong when checking for empty title and description, here:

```
if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(title) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(description_val)) {
```

it should be:

```
public void createPost() {
    String title_val = title.getText().toString().trim();
    String post_description_val = description.getText().toString().trim();
    String user_id=mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
    if (!title_val.isEmpty() && !post_description_val.isEmpty()) {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Map<String, String> posts = new HashMap<>();
        posts.put("description",description_val);
        posts.put("title", title);
        posts.put("user_id", user_id);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        db.collection("posts")
                .add(posts)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentReference>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(DocumentReference documentReference) {
                        Toast.makeText( Post.this,"Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Log.w( TAG,"Error adding document", e);
                    }
                });
    }

}
```

**EDIT:**

For testing purposes your rules should look like this, later you need to update them to make them more secure:
[image]

Comment: Levi I updated the question,you can look at the full code.it doesnt solve my problem

Comment: Ok, I have run your code and it works fine for me. I have some questions: 1 are you authenticated when you reach the Post activity? 2 is Firestore activated in your firebase console? 3 is you Firestore  rules allowing write? 4 could you replace you textutils method with simply title_val.isEmpty() and position_description_val.isEmpty()?

Comment: 1.Yes 2.I think so all the dependencies are okay 3.where do I see this?4.I tried with removing the !,the code doesnt run

Comment: I've updated the code to make it work for question #4. Also I've added the location where you can see #3

Comment: Lev can you help me a lil with other question

Comment: Yeah sure, what is it?

Comment: I am having a prb with the back option,check my new question